# Best way to transfer the data's from MS-Access to MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, ms-access, data-transfer

I am using `My-Sql` database.
I have `MS-Access` as external database .
The `MS-Access` database contains the original data's .

***I want to do** :*

Need to retrieve the data's from `MS-Access` database , to `My-Sql` database table

***To achieve this task what i am thinking is :***

- Create a java class to retrieve the data's from `MS-Access`
- Store the data's into my database `My-Sql`
- Use `Thread` concept to run the java class for simultaneous process(every 10 mins)

  I want your suggestion for this, Whether my point is correct? 
  If not , **Is there any way to achieve this task simply**...!

Comment: you can also use any scheduler for this purpose.Quartz is good one.To learn Quartz [follow the link](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/)

Comment: if this is just for migrating data and not just for an application, import your Access database in MySql directly

Comment: Quartz must be your pick. You would have to code for retrieving and storing in java and plug to Quartz

Comment: @javadoc If `Quartz` is a good choice for job-scheduling ,  thaanks for you suggestion

Comment: @Deepanshu ..Thanks..Is there any option is available to transfer the data's

Comment: @kark is there any UI of Mysql ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: @Deepanshu yes, I am doing this process for `JSF` application..and the link you given is for importing `CSV` file not for `MDB(MS-Access)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from [quartz-scheduler](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/)

**quartz-scheduler**

It is an great feature fro java to fix the time for at which time program being executed

*To transfer the data from MS-Access to `MySql` what is did is*

- Created a java class that retrieve the data from MS-Access for every
- 10 min   Created a java class that perform to copy the retrieved data
- into My-Sql   Converted these two classes into Executable EXE file
- I deployed it in windows schedular task(Automatic execution when the
  system boot)