# How to change the data from excel to database (my sql)?

Tags: mysql, excel

I don't want t put the data inside one by one,how to put a great quantity data by one time?
My data in Excel .want to change into database(my sql)

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database  i think it helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to migrate from excel to mysql, there are plenty like https://www.webyog.com/product/downloads/
if its just about loading data you can use go through this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

```
convert your excel to csv  and upload using following script
<?php 
include 'connection.php'; 
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) 
{
//get the csv file
$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");

while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) 
{  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2,col3) VALUES 
  ( 
  '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
  '".addslashes($data[1])."',
  '".addslashes($data[2])."'


  ) 
 ") or die(mysql_error()); 

header('Location: home.php');
  } 

}
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
Choose your file:<input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```