# How can I convert .xls file to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, excel, xls

My sample data column in my xls is:

```
|numbers | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|  1     | a | b | c |
|  2     |a.1|b.2|c.3|
```

I have a table of in MySQL table

```
|numbers | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

I'm using this code

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/a.xls'
INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

My Result becomes especial characters, how can I get the full detail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import an excel file in to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP knowledge you can code a script and use the PHPExcel library.

Otherwise I guess you could open xls in Excel save it as CSV and then use LOAD DATA INFILE query.