# insert data into table that value Import from CSV

Tags: sql, csv, insert, db2

I have a list of data in excel list , how can i import them and insert into current created table. May i know the sql query for import excel data and insert into table ??Any help would be appreciated.

My excel list .CSV
[image]

table describe
[image]

new table with 0 record (13 columns same as excel list)
[image]

Comment: did u try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database or this http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html

Comment: It's not working on db2sql

Comment: normally i use 'Kettle' a data integration tool for complex data imports and extractions maybe you can try that. It's free to use http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/

Answer (score 0):

DB2 has the `IMPORT` and `LOAD` for getting external data into tables. In your case I would recommend [IMPORT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html).

This would be the general statement:
`import from yourfile of del insert into mytable`

When you go to the documentation there are so-called "file type modifiers" that can be used to tell DB2 about the format of the data, the codepage, separators between the columns and more.