# Import excel data sheet to java frame jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jdk1.7

Looking for help to import excel sheet data to java frame table or directly import to mysql database using java application

Comment: Expect Help Not Code !!!

Comment: Use `Apache-POI` for reading Exel data and `JDBC` to put data into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

1. To directly import the data into MySQL database, the following thread already discussed that into details : [How to import an excel file in to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database)
2. Mysql also provides an add-in tools (Excel for Mysql) for Microsoft Excel that enables you to open MySQL database within Excel and export the data. More reference about this can be found at https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_guide_to_exporting and https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/
3. Also, you can use MySQL "LOAD DATA" command. You can read more about that online