# Importing Excel Table to MySQL Arabic Data

Tags: mysql, excel

I have imported an EXCEL File to mySQL database. The database is imported but when it comes to arabic chars they don't appear. it gives me blank fields. 
The steps I used : 
1- Save the Excel as CSV.
2- Import from mysql

Comment: The CSV would have been saved in your machine's default encoding; did you tell MySQL that was the file's character set upon import?

Comment: I choose the char as utf8. And when importing, the records which contain arabic data it says "Affected". Do I have to change the encoding from the Excel first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is Excel2MySQL.  It will handle all possible unicode characters.  There are also other options that can import unicode... see this post: [How to import an excel file in to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578291/259538)