# How to export excel data into Mysql tables

Tags: mysql, excel

How can we **export Excel data into Mysql table**. Is there any plugIn in excel for converting data into mysql table or in any other methods?

Comment: convert your excel into csv file then use phpmyadmin import options, your csv file  should have equal number of columns as in table

Comment: @zan : Ok this is useful for me.

Comment: looking for .csv direct bulk export or only excel?

Comment: @lti : only from excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an excel file in to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your Excel to CSV first then import in phpmyadmin. The number of columns in csv should be equal to number of columns in table, If you have auto increment for first column then leave first column of CSV blank.

[image]

IF you dont use phpmyadmin [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database) will help you out with import.

Comment: Is there any direct plug in for exporting excel into mysql table?

Comment: what are you on , Mac or PC ?

Comment: Windows machine, /i mean any plugin in excel for doing that?

Comment: There are many , it depends on how you want to use it , see attached links it have lot of other info which may help you

Comment: This is helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write by [this.](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/creatingreading-an-excel-file-in-android/)
and also store data to your sqlite database table from .xls files cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your data in CSV format(comma separated values)  format in a file then you can use **LOAD DATA** command to load the data from file to table

Example -

LOAD DATA INFILE 'path_of_file' INTO TABLE 'name_of_table'

more information on load data can be found in MySQL manuals available online

Comment: Over your MySQL workbench console or query execution client

Answer (score 0):

In case you convert Excel into CSV, then there is a way for bulk export:

```
query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '"+"\\FileName.csv"+"' INTO TABLE Table_Name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (Column_Name,....)";
```

Make sure, you match the table columns with the file(.csv) columns, to avoid error.