# Migrate data from PDF file to MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdf, upload

I have a PDF file containing thousands of entries like `userId`,`userName` etc.
Is there any way to insert these into a MySQL database?

Comment: Can you break this out into a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

You Actually can not import data from a **PDF** file

An work around is 
to convert the file to an excel and importing from it

1. To convert pdf to excel

https://www.freepdfconvert.com/pdf-excel

2. To Import data from excel to Database

[How to import an excel file in to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-off file you can copy and paste the contents into excel, save as CSV and import into you mysql table.

You can also parse it, there's plenty of libraries to convert pdf data into text, which such text can be then further parsed and inserted into your table.

If you need to do it in mass, then I suggest get a mass converter like [this pdf to mysql indexer](https://www.chronoapps.com/product/osiris-pdf-to-mysql-indexer/), then parse the indexed data into structured content.