# excel file upload to database using Php

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am trying to upload excel .xls file but got an error when I am trying to import autoload file my web page going blank and when I comment it its works. I can't Import file of spout extenstion of reader. Here this is my code.

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory; 
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

require_once 'http://localhost/muddy/admin/spout-2.7.2/src/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php';//Error cant import
```

here in this require once cant upload file if I write this code my web page going blank !

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
    echo "ks";
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls')
        && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {
        $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        // Read excel file by using ReadFactory object.
        $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
        // Open file
        $reader->open($inputFileName);
        $count = 1;

       foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
            echo "ks22";
            // Number of Rows in Excel sheet
            foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                echo "ks32";
                // It reads data after header. In the my excel sheet,
                // header is in the first row.
                if ($count > 1) {
                    echo "ks4";
                    // Data of excel sheet
                    $data['Member_no'] = $row[0];
                    $data['Member_name'] = $row[1];
                    $data['Gender'] = $row[2];
                    $data['Club_name'] = $row[3];
                    $data['member_since'] = $row[4];
                    $data['Expiry_date'] = $row[3];

                    $member_no = $data['Member_no'];
                    $member_name = $data['Member_name'];
                    $gender = $data['Gender'];
                    $club_name = $data['Club_name'];
                    $member_since = $data['member_since'];
                    $expiry_date = $data['Expiry_date'];

                    $query="INSERT INTO `mmholdin_management`.`Club_member` (Member_no`, `Member_name`, `Gender`, `Club_name`, `member_since`, `Expiry_date`) VALUES ($member_no ,$member_name, $gender,$club_name,$member_since,$expiry_date)";
                echo $query;
                    if(mysql_query($query))
                    {
                        $msg = "Record Saved!";
                        //header("Location:managecustomer.php");
                        exit;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $msg = "Unable to Save!";

                    }

                    print_r(data);

                }
                $count++;
            }
        }

        // Close excel file
        $reader->close();

    } else {

        echo "Please Select Valid Excel File";
    }

} else {

    //echo "Please Select Excel File";

}
```

Comment: why not simply use `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: csv code will able to import xls extension file? @Jenish

Comment: Load data infile is work for xls file, is csv file extensuion code will work for xls file ?@Rahul

Comment: check `mysql workbench` may be you got your solution i don't really know does it work or not bt you can check its simple may be it support your upload file format. doc link https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

try this example.

```
 $file = "your-file.xls";
 $handle = fopen($file, "r");
 $c = 0;
 while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
 {
 $name = $filesop[0];
 $email = $filesop[1];

 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO xls (name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')");
 }

 if($sql){
 echo "You database has imported successfully";
 }else{
 echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
 }
```

check this: https://www.studytutorial.in/how-to-upload-or-import-an-excel-file-into-mysql-database-using-spout-library-using-php

Comment: This code Not Working ! I have code from this link referance but not working!

Comment: it cant read value from xsl file . when i try to print  $name and its empty!

Comment: Spout supports XSLX files, but not XLS files... (looks like you're trying to read an XLS file)