# Import from Self-contained File - MySQL Workbench

Tags: excel, import, mysql-workbench

## Description:

I'm having a trouble to import an excel file in **MySQL Workbench** (Data Import/Restore < Import from Disk < Import from Self-Contained File < choose Target Schema < Start Import) containing two tables with four columns and *over 50000* rows.

## Dataset:

For example, my Excel table looks like this:

| List_ID | List_Parent_ID | Action | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1421853 | 1421853 | ONLINE | 01/31/2010 23:40:03 |
| 1382755 | 1382755 | ONLINE | 01/19/2010 23:40:00 |

## The error message:

`ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'PK'.`

## Remarks:

I tried some tools suggested in ([How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql/17666285#17666285)) and ([How to import an excel file in to a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database)); but the below-mentioned problems occur:

1. [Data Converter](https://thdoan.github.io/mr-data-converter/) which gets an excel file; however the results for datatime are not correct and my query encountered an error:

`INSERT INTO DailyList   (List_ID, List_Parent_ID, Action, DateTime) VALUES   (1392893,1392893,'ONLINE','1/3/2010 23:40') Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '1/3/2010 23:40' for column 'DateTime'`

2. [SQLizer.io](http://sqlizer.io/) which is free for anything up to 5000 rows.

## Expect:

Ideally, I am seeking to successfully import the excel file with all rows and columns in a correct format into MySQL Workbench.

Comment: EXACTLY how are you trying to import the data?  You aren't literally importing a `.xlsx` file and hoping that the tool knows how to handle it, are you?  The fact that it mentions "PK" suggests you are (because those are the first two characters of a .xlsx file). That's simply not how it works.  You have to transform the xlsx into an SQL format.  You can do that with a script pretty easily.

Comment: I was curious whether the option of importing all types in Workbench does not mean that I can also upload other types not only sql files. @TimRoberts could you possibly help me with that script you mentioned?

Comment: Without knowing your level of expertise, that's questionable.  However, MySQL Workbench is perfectly happy to import CSV files, and Excel is perfectly happy to save a spreadsheet as a CSV file.  That's probably your best road to happiness.  Is your DateTime field stored as a string, or is it actually a date/time column?

Comment: The DateTime field is stored as string in the file.

Comment: Then you have to make sure the datetime format of the data complies with mysql's datetime format requirements. Alternative is to use a proper ETL tool, like SSIS to do the import of the excel file.

Comment: @Shadow, that type of the column in the file should be changed as well as that of ids. However, my problem is not related to the columns' types as far as I understood.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import excel file into MySQL Workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989375/how-to-import-excel-file-into-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Based on the results from "Data Converter", the format of your date string is EXACTLY your problem.  You need to have a way to convert that to an SQL date/time format.

Answer (score 0):

Here I want to elaborate more on how I successfully converted my file in *MySQL Workbench 8.0*:

**Input data:** Excel file having a table (listings) with DateTime in string
**Steps**:

1. Convert an Excel file into CSV (right-click and save it as CSV)
2. Use Pandas to transform DateTime into the desired format

```
import pandas as pd
dataset_paths = 'Logs.csv'
    
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_paths)
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.to_csv('updated_file_logs.csv', index=False)
```

3. Choose a table in the scheme < click Table Data Import Wizard < select file to import < select destination table ([see the answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989375/how-to-import-excel-file-into-mysql-workbench))