# How do I import and Excel Spreadsheet into my DB?

Tags: sql, excel, insert, dbm

**Hi Everyone, I'm trying to import some data from an excel sheet across three different tables, and I'm wondering how I can do this I can't find anything for actually importing in excel. I don't know how to write an intelligent INSERT for this. HELP!**

This is my table structure.

Jobs {
[id] [entity_id] [round_id] [company_id] [address_id] [vendor_id] [first_service_date] [name] [price] [type] [status] [notes] [vendor_sort_id] [subcontractor_sort_id] [job_type_id] [auto_complete] [aworka_slug] [deleted_at] [created_at] [updated_at] [use_fixed_price] [fixed_price] [store_code}[last_service_date] [is_credit_note]
}

Frequency_Rule_Job{
[id] [job_id] [frequency_rule_id] [effective_from] [created_at] [updated_at] [deleted_at] [is_active]
}

Frequency_Rules {
[id] [freq] [interval] [week_days] [company_id] [text] [created_at] [updated_at] [json_week_days] [setpos] [count] [deleted_at]
}

Here is example data

Jobs
[image]

Frequency_Rules
[image: ![enter image description here]

Frequency_Rule_job
[image]

This is the excel data I'm trying to mass insert.

[image]

Edit: Forgot to add that my DB is MySQL

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data as formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: MySQL - images can be zoomed. What sort of format do people usually want sample table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is Microsoft SQL server, create a SSIS(SQL Server Integration Services) project and insert your excel data to database as you want.

Comment: It's a MySQL DB - know any solutions or start me on the right path to a solution?

Comment: Check this link for ways to import Excel data to MySQL. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310166/how-to-import-an-excel-file-in-to-a-mysql-database)